# Asking for coverage of travel expenses

Tags: professionalism

Suppose you have an onsite interview. Is it bad practice to ask the company to pay for a hotel for you if you live far away from the office?

Comment: Some companies do it. It depends how much a) you want the job and b) how much they want you ;)

Answer (score 3):

No it is not bad practise. If they have sought after you, they likely know where you are located but their answer is hugely dependent on the company policy. Also it will show you have the confidence to put yourself out there which may work in your favour.

In some cases, all your expenses including travel, accommodation and a meal or two are covered. Also another common practice is for a company to pay for your lodging as long as you pay for your transportation. In my experience, potential employees are more likely to be expected to cover their own travel expenses for junior jobs and jobs for non-profit companies.

If you are driving there, I personally would drive there before the interview and sleep in my car after if I wanted the job so much. Although not ideal it is another solution.

If they will not cover your expenses, some of your expenses may be tax deductible. If you travel to look for a new job in your present occupation, you may be able to deduct your travel expenses but this will vary depending on your location.

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose you have an onsite interview. Is it bad practice to ask the
>   company to pay for a hotel for you if you live far away from the
>   office?

No, it's not bad practice.

It's good practice to avoid surprises. It's good practice not to assume when you aren't sure.

Ask if the company will pay expenses, which expenses will be paid, what limits there would be, and what the process will be for getting reimbursed.

Either the company will indicate that no expenses will be reimbursed, or they will provide their policy. Then you can act accordingly.

Either way - no surprises.

Answer (score 1):

It is not bad practice to ask before accepting the invitation for an interview. Further, if they won't pay your expenses it is not a bad practice to then decline the interview. If they say they will, you can ask as many followup questions as you like (what they'll cover, what receipts to keep, how to submit them, and so on.)

It is, however, a bad idea to accept the interview, come to it, and then at the end of the interview ask for the first time if you will be reimbursed. This puts the interviewer on the spot, and if the policy is not to reimburse they may feel really bad about that. Find out in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If they are paying for your flight to get to the interview, they'll 100% also pay for your hotel as well.  Doesn't make sense to pay for one but not the other.  If you are driving yourself to the interview then it certainly is reasonable for them to pay for a hotel.  But it depends on the level of job as well.  I'd say for junior roles, it's probably not as appropriate.  What kind of job is it and how badly do they want you?